# At startup, open the specified ViewController

Tags: ios, swift3, xcode8

I have two VC (**ViewController**, **SettingsVC**, **VC2**).

How can I make it so that when you turn on the **Switch**(located in **SettingsVC**) when the application starts it would be shown **VC2**??

The default is **ViewController**.

[image]

Comment: is there any Splash screen controller is there in your app ?

Answer (score 0):

Write this code in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` -

```
let isSwitchOn = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "isSwitchOn")
if isSwitchOn {
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let vc2 = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Your identifier")
self.window!.rootViewController = vc2;
}
```

Set `isSwitchOn` in `SettingsVC` like this -

```
UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "isSwitchOn")
```